# Show that the condition of transitivity of the relation $\mathcal{R}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{R}\circ\mathcal{R}\subset\mathcal{R}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let us assume that $\mathcal{R}\subset X^{2}$ is transitive, that is to say, given $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ in $\mathcal{R}$, then $(x,z)$ also belongs to $\mathcal{R}$. According to such property, one has
\begin{align*}
(x,z)\in\mathcal{R}\circ\mathcal{R} \Longrightarrow \exists y\,(y\in X)\wedge(x\mathcal{R}y)\wedge(y\mathcal{R}z)) \Longrightarrow (x,z)\in\mathcal{R}\Longrightarrow\mathcal{R}\circ\mathcal{R}\subset\mathcal{R}.
\end{align*}

Now it is time to go backwards. Let us prove it by contradiction. Assume that $x\mathcal{R}y$ and $y\mathcal{R}z$, but $(x,z)\not\in\mathcal{R}$. According to the definition of composition of relations, we have
\begin{align*}
(x,z)\in\mathcal{R}\circ\mathcal{R}\subset\mathcal{R}\Longrightarrow (x,z)\in\mathcal{R}
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction, as proposed.

**MY QUESTION**

Can someone double check my solution and provide a geometrical interpretation for such result?

Comment: What do you mean with a geometrical interpretation?

Comment: You may think of $\mathcal{R}$ as the binary relation between lines $a$ and $b$ which belong to the same plane: $(a,b)\in\mathcal{R}$ iff $a$ and $b$ are parallel.

Comment: But that relation is just some example of a transitive relation, not really a geometrical interpretation of it...

Comment: That's what I meant. I would like to interpret it in some geometrical context, even though it is a particular case.

Comment: Perhaps a nice way to visualise the theorem, is by viewing a relation as a directed graph: two vertices $x$ and $y$ are related $x\mathcal Ry$ if there is an arrow going from $x$ to $y$. Transitivity says that if we can make a path of length $2$ by following arrows, then the start and end node are directly connected by an arrow. The statement that $\mathcal R\circ\mathcal R\subset\mathcal R$ states basically the same thing; that the graph consisting of the direct connections of the paths of length $2$ is a subgraph of the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulation could be a little more careful, e.g. "$(x,z)\in\mathcal R$" in itself does not imply "$\mathcal R\circ\mathcal R\subset \mathcal R$", as your last arrow seems to say. Apart from that, the argument is correct.

Note that your argument does not make use of proof by contradiction: is not necessary to start with assuming $\mathcal R$ is not transitive (and in fact that assumption is not used in your argument). If you leave that assumption out, the whole proof still stands: $\mathcal R\circ \mathcal R\subset \mathcal R$ and $x\mathcal Ry$ and $y\mathcal Rz$ implies that $(x,z)\in\mathcal R\circ\mathcal R$, thus $x \mathcal Rz$ by inclusion and since $x,y,z$ were arbitrary we see that $\mathcal R$ is transitive.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It was really helpful.